# How to add a tag to bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css

I got this sidebar but I wonder how can I add an item to the bottom of the sidebar. here is the current code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Dummy
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently, when I add an item to the sidebar it comes just below the last item, I want it to be at the bottom end even when the content side has a scroll bar, like the profile icon seen in most apps

Comment: If you are referring to your dummy div the first thing to to is **actually put in inside the sidebar**.

Comment: Also why does the content div have a height of 1000px? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what I need is to add an item to sidebar "logout", but it should appear at the end of the sidebar. Not just below "About"

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to to is actually put your extra element **inside** the sidebar then leverage flexbox column layout,

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 6px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>

  <div class="content">
    Dummy
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Deiakk96 that is actually the correct solution. The important info here is, that within `flexbox`, `margin: auto` will consume all remaining space. As such the `margin-top: auto` for the dummy div will consume all remaing space and push it down to the bottom.